# Make checkboxes act like radio buttons in duplicatable input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a duplicate-able div's containing check box's, at the moment on the original set of inputs, the check boxes act like radio buttons, but when duplicated it still only works on the first not the second.

Also on submit it only returns one value for the original form in the console, but no value for any duplicates.

Any help greatly appreciated.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/EEd7c/

jQuery:

```
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking
//General Variables
var relation_input_groups = ["relation-group-1"];
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var relation_fields=[0];
var relation_input ="<label>Spouse</label>"+

    "<input type='checkbox' value='spouse' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>own child</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='ownchild' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>adopted</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='adopted' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>stepchild</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='stepchild' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>parent</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='parent' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>inlaw</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='inlaw' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>brother</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='brother' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
    "<label>other</label>"+ 

    "<input type='checkbox' value='other' class='relationship' name='relationship' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    //populate jquery generated fields
    jQuery(relation_fields).each(function() 
    {
        jQuery(relation_input).appendTo('#relation-group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() 
    {
        clone_dependant();
    });
    function clone_dependant() 
    {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var relation_newDiv = 'relation-group-'+ g_counter;
        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#relation-group-1').attr('id',"relation-group-" + g_counter );
        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input').val('');
        $clonedDiv.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);

        relation_input_groups.push(relation_newDiv);
    }
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation
    //submit function
    var $unique = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $unique.click(function() 
    {
        $unique.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });

    var result = {};
    var dependants;
    var dep_counter = 0;
    jQuery('#submit').click(function()
    {
        jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v)
        {
            dep_counter++
            dependants = {};
            result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
            dependants['relationship'] = $(v).find('.relationship:checked').val();
        });
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(jsonData);
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    <div id="label">relationship:</div> <div id="relation-group-1"></div>
</div>

<button id="clone">clone</button>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you not using radio buttons? [Let me guess you do not like the look]

Comment: nope, not at all the case... although i really don't :/.. long story short, i need to replicate the look of a real everyday form and this form has check box's.. not circles you color in :)..

Comment: Plural of `checkbox` is `checkboxes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is you are not attaching the click events to the new cloned elements.

```
$(document).on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings(":checked").removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: what would you suggest, I thought 'input[type="checkbox"]' would target all of them...

Comment: Targets them only for the elements that are on the page at that moment in time.

Comment: thank you for all your help... really thanks... like i would have most likely used the live example... i may be pushing it.. but the submit button only returning values for the first and not the duplicates. is that an entirely new question or

Comment: if you can could perhaps look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360329/duplicate-able-checkboxes-only-returns-value-for-orginal-not-duplicates

Comment: hi, Ive recently had to group the checkboxes in divs and since then this code hasn't been working http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/EEd7c/10/

Comment: well you broke the siblings relationship. Without testing it will be something like `$(this).parent().siblings().find(":checked").removeAttr('checked');`

Answer (score 2):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/EEd7c/1/

```
var $unique = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$unique.live("click", function() {
$(this).siblings().removeAttr('checked');
$(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Yet Live is deprecated...

Or

```
$(document).on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
$(this).siblings().removeAttr('checked');
$(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: @epascarello strongly recommends not using live though.. live is deprecated after all.. and when using that code with on instead of live, it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

```
var $unique = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$unique.live('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Using `live` to register the event handler to dynamically created elements. $unique variable will contain only the initial set of checkboxes.

Comment: It still has the same problem as the original! Going to blow away all the checkboxes.

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven Are you sure it works perfectly? Select one in the first group and one in the last. What happens?

Comment: @epascarello, I assume you are the downvoter. Check my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6GuNP/3/

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven It does not work! It removes the checkboxes from **ALL** the sections.

Comment: And again live is deprecated. Do not use live! Use on.

Comment: Updated the anwer. The problem here is attaching the event listener properly. And the question never mentioned that selecting checkbox in one group should not unselect checkbox in other group. So, that's not a BUG.

Comment: It is a bug, they are to act like them are in groups. LOL And again, get rid of live() it is outdated for multiple versions of jQuery and it is being removed in the next version. Make upgrading easier and get rid of it.