# duplicate-able checkboxes only returns value for orginal not duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this was actually orginally in another question ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359615/make-checkboxes-act-like-radio-buttons-in-duplicatable-input-fields)) that had two parts. The first part was solved by @epascarello - thanks again, now just this part remaining, and i don't seem to get it.

I'm creating a duplicate-able div's containing checkboxes, on submit it only returns one value for the original input in the console, but no value for any duplicates.

Any help greatly appreciated.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/EEd7c/

jQuery:

```
//Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking
//General Variables
var relation_input_groups = ["relation-group-1"];
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var relation_fields=[0];
var relation_input ="<label>Spouse</label>"+

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='spouse' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>own child</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='ownchild' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>adopted</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='adopted' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>stepchild</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='stepchild' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>parent</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='parent' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>inlaw</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='inlaw' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>brother</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='brother' class='relationship' name='relationship' />" +
                    "<label>other</label>"+ 

                    "<input type='checkbox' value='other' class='relationship' name='relationship' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //populate jquery generated fields
    jQuery(relation_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(relation_input).appendTo('#relation-group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });
    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var relation_newDiv = 'relation-group-'+ g_counter;
        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#relation-group-1').attr('id',"relation-group-" + g_counter );
        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input').val('');
        $clonedDiv.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);

        relation_input_groups.push(relation_newDiv);
    }
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation
//submit function
$(document).on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings(":checked").removeAttr('checked');
});

var result = {};
var dependants;
var dep_counter = 0;
jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
    jQuery('.dependant').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        result['dependant'+dep_counter] = [dependants];
        dependants['relationship'] = $(v).find('.relationship:checked').val();
    });
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(jsonData);
});
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="dependant-1" class="dependant">
    <div id="label">relationship:</div> <div id="relation-group-1"></div>
</div>

<button id="clone">clone</button>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EEd7c/7/

Comment this line : `$clonedDiv.find('input').val('');`

Also set `dep_counter = 0;` on  `submit` button click..

Comment: hey, don't know if this is appropriate, but ur answers are usually quiet brilliant, could you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374324/jquery-clone-able-inputs-foreach-overwrites-values/

Answer (score 1):

Your cloned check boxes do not have any values assigned to it.  Ensure that when its cloned the values are set in the net set of checkboxes

Comment: This comment "// You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value" was the source of your problem. In fact yes you do. and you are setting them empty here $clonedDiv.find('input').val('');

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because those checkboxes have the same `name` attribute. When the submit button is pressed, it serializes the values of all the form controls (text boxes, radio boxes, check boxes, etc) and send them. The name property should be unique for all those controls.

In your code, all those checkboxes have the same `name` property (relationship) which makes them indistinguishable. A fix to this problem is to give different names to those check boxes.